# Efficient way to categorize data into bins in python

Tags: python

Suppose I have a floating point dataset (x) which can assume any values between 0.0 and 1.0. I want to categorized the data into custom bins,eg,:

```
    cat= 0 # the output category
    if x > 0.8 and x<=0.9:
        cat = 1
    if x > 0.7 and x<=0.8:
        cat=2
    if x>0.6 and x<=0.7:
        cat = 3
```

and so on...   Is this the most efficient (in terms of how many lines i have to write) way to do this?  I was thinking whether there is some way where i just specify the lower and upper range of the category and the category number and not have to write so many if statements.

Comment: how about `pandas.cut`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html

Comment: Are all the bins the same size?

Comment: BTW, you should be using `elif` to avoid unnecessary tests. And you can simplify those tests, eg `elif 0.6 < x <= 0.7:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you move the data into pandas dataframe

```
df['data'] = pd.DataFrame(x)
binInterval = [0, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
binLabels   = [0, 4, 3, 2, 1]
df['binned'] = pd.cut(df['data'], bins = binInterval, labels=binLabels)
```

refer documentaion [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html)

Answer (score 0):

simply:

```
categories = [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
cat = [categories[i]<x and categories[i+1]>=x for i in range(0, len(categories)-1)].index(True) + 1
```